# Fatal error initializing plugin org.jetbrains.android

Tags: intellij-idea

I get the error int the title in IntelliJ IDEA Version 2017.3.5 when I try to create a new empty project (or any other kind of project). 
What I have done so far is:

- download the community version (without jdk) from here
  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linuxWithoutJDK&code=IIC
- Move that to my home folder, extract it, follow the instructions
  in the Install-Linux-tar.txt
- Open the IDE, select empty project, name it, and press finish

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I tried deleting the Andriod folder in the plugins folder, but that achieved nothing.

Here is the text from the idea.log file:

> 2018-03-17 16:15:53,986 [      0]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------  2018-03-17 16:15:53,993 [      7]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User
>
> scale factor: 1.0  2018-03-17 16:15:53,993 [      7]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.25 (IDE-managed HiDPI)  2018-03-17 16:15:54,004 [     18]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-173.4674.33, 05 Mar 2018 14:53)  2018-03-17 16:15:54,004 [     18]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (4.13.0-37-generic, amd64)  2018-03-17 16:15:54,004 [     18]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 9.0.1+11 (Oracle Corporation)  2018-03-17 16:15:54,004 [     18]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 9.0.1+11 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)  2018-03-17 16:15:54,004 [     18]   INFO -
>
> ## com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/max/intelij/idea-IC-173.4674.33/lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine -XX:ErrorFile=/home/max/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/max/java_error_in_IDEA.hprof -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2017.3 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/max/intelij/idea-IC-173.4674.33/bin/idea64.vmoptions
>
> -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true  2018-03-17 16:15:54,005 [     19]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main -
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool:
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@279c624e[Running, parallelism = 3,
>   size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions
>   = 0]  2018-03-17 16:15:54,005 [     19]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: UTF-8  2018-03-17 16:15:54,021 [     35]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library
>   (64-bit) loaded in 16 ms  2018-03-17 16:15:54,169 [    183]   INFO -
>   llij.openapi.wm.impl.X11UiUtil - cannot initialize 
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe
>   cannot be cast to jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.X11UiUtil$Xlib.getInstance(X11UiUtil.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.X11UiUtil$Xlib.access$400(X11UiUtil.java:55)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.X11UiUtil.(X11UiUtil.java:238)
>     at
>   com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.patchSystem(IdeaApplication.java:170)
>     at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.(IdeaApplication.java:91)
>     at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$start$1(MainImpl.java:45)    at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
>   2018-03-17 16:15:54,171 [    185]   INFO -
>   .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: null  2018-03-17
>   16:15:54,589 [    603]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -
>   Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml  2018-03-17
>   16:15:55,173 [   1187]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 35
>   plugins initialized in 745 ms  2018-03-17 16:15:55,174 [   1188]
>   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins:
>   Android Support (10.2.3), Ant Support (1.0), Bytecode Viewer (0.1),
>   CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (173.4674.33), Eclipse
>   Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (173.4674.33), Git Integration (8.1),
>   GitHub (173.4674.33), Gradle (173.4674.33), Groovy (9.0), I18n for
>   Java (173.4674.33), IDEA CORE (173.4674.33), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit
>   (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (173.4674.33), Java Stream Debugger
>   (173.4674.33), JavaFX (1.0), Kotlin (1.2.10-release-IJ2017.3-1), Maven
>   Integration (173.4674.33), Mercurial Integration (10.0), Plugin DevKit
>   (1.0), Properties Support (173.4674.33), Settings Repository
>   (173.4674.33), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0),
>   Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), UI Designer (173.4674.33), XPathView +
>   XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (173.4674.33)  2018-03-17
>   16:15:55,175 [   1189]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -
>   Loaded custom plugins: IDE Features Trainer (0.8.59), IdeaVim (0.49) 
>   2018-03-17 16:15:56,069 [   2083]   INFO -
>   ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10;
>   max=705  2018-03-17 16:15:56,111 [   2125]   INFO -
>   pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher:
>   /home/max/intelij/idea-IC-173.4674.33/bin/fsnotifier64  2018-03-17
>   16:15:56,127 [   2141]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl -
>   Native file watcher is operational.  2018-03-17 16:15:57,150 [   3164]
>   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading
>   com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity@50339df6 
>   2018-03-17 16:15:57,313 [   3327]   INFO -
>   til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
>   2018-03-17 16:15:57,357 [   3371]   INFO -
>   rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
>   2018-03-17 16:15:57,418 [   3432]   INFO -
>   gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release  2018-03-17
>   16:15:57,735 [   3749]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index
>   exts enumerated:236  2018-03-17 16:15:57,747 [   3761]   INFO -
>   il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:11  2018-03-17
>   16:15:57,788 [   3802]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All
>   stub exts enumerated:26  2018-03-17 16:15:57,789 [   3803]   INFO -
>   tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
>   2018-03-17 16:15:58,394 [   4408]   INFO -
>   plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 87 application components initialized
>   in 3970ms  2018-03-17 16:15:58,422 [   4436]   INFO -
>   .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 5675 ms 
>   2018-03-17 16:15:59,018 [   5032]   INFO -
>   pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1274  2018-03-17
>   16:15:59,086 [   5100]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization -
>   Initialization done:67  2018-03-17 16:15:59,433 [   5447]   INFO -
>   com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0;
>   restored: fontSize=15, fontScale=1.25  2018-03-17 16:15:59,435 [
>   5449]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=15,
>   fontScale=1.25; restored: fontSize=15, fontScale=1.25  2018-03-17
>   16:16:00,333 [   6347]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20
>   project components initialized in 494 ms  2018-03-17 16:16:00,490 [
>   6504]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin
>   list (updated at 3/17/18, 2:57 PM)  2018-03-17 16:16:01,251 [   7265] 
>   ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl -
>   javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema   at
>   com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>     at
>   com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.sdk.AndroidSdks.tryToChooseSdkHandler(AndroidSdks.java:153)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.getRepoManager(SdkComponentSource.java:94)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.initIfNecessary(SdkComponentSource.java:65)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.getComponents(SdkComponentSource.java:141)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.updater.SdkComponentSource.getAvailableVersions(SdkComponentSource.java:122)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.updateExternal(UpdateChecker.kt:297)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.doUpdateAndShowResult(UpdateChecker.kt:140)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$updateAndShowResult$1.run(UpdateChecker.kt:89)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
>   PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.2.3]
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6a0da322    at
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 17 more 2018-03-17 16:16:01,256 [   7270]  ERROR -
>   plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5  Build
>
> ## IC-173.4674.33  2018-03-17 16:16:01,256 [   7270]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 9.0.1  2018-03-17 16:16:01,256 [
>
> 7270]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM)
>   64-Bit Server VM  2018-03-17 16:16:01,256 [   7270]  ERROR -
>   plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
>   2018-03-17 16:16:01,259 [   7273]  ERROR -
>   plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Linux  2018-03-17 16:16:01,259 [ 
>   7273]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action:
>   2018-03-17 16:16:01,683 [   7697]   INFO -
>   .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@61017684 
>   2018-03-17 16:16:04,088 [  10102]   INFO -
>   .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading
>   com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@57e90c42 
>   2018-03-17 16:16:04,284 [  10298]   INFO -
>   .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@576a8991 
>   2018-03-17 16:16:06,654 [  12668]   INFO -
>   roject.impl.ProjectManagerImpl - Fatal error initializing plugin
>   org.jetbrains.android 
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing plugin org.jetbrains.android   at
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:271)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:404)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:289)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.newProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.ex.ProjectManagerEx.createProject(ProjectManagerEx.java:74)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ProjectBuilder.createProject(ProjectBuilder.java:77)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.doCreate(NewProjectUtil.java:110)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createFromWizard(NewProjectUtil.java:76)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createNewProject(NewProjectUtil.java:71)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction.actionPerformed(NewProjectAction.java:36)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:67)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:156)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:80)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:352)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6578)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3343)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6343)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2259)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4961)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2317)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4539)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4480)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2303)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2758)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:99)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
>   Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException:
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]  ... 52
>   more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException  at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)     at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:385)
>     ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android,
>   10.2.3] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6a0da322    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 52 more 2018-03-17 16:16:08,039 [  14053]   INFO -
>   j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 1123 ms spent to cache options in
>   application

Comment: Please share the logs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085.

Comment: Apologies for format. I tried putting in block quotes, code, etc, none of it really worked. Trying to find nicer way to post logs

Comment: Use some file or text sharing service and post the link instead.

Comment: Please use Java 8 to run IntelliJ IDEA, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879. Java 9 is not supported yet for runtime.

Answer (score 10):

Choose "Configure"-->"Plugins", and deselect "Android Support", restart the IDE and then you can create the project successfully.